# Bytes written is 0 although getOverlappedResult returns 1

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, 64-bit

I'm trying to write hex data to my serial port. However, although GetOverlappedResult returns true, the number of bytes sent is always 0 despite my sending 1 or 2 or 8 bytes.

I'm able to open/close the port and receive hex messages. I just can't figure how to write data to my serial port for it to be picked up by another virtual serial port.

I referenced a 'TimeReader' project a colleague found online. I've tested the ports with virtual serial ports using Serial Port Utility, and managed to communicate successfully between them. Searching online did not help me solve the problem entirely.

How I create the handle:

```cpp
serialPortHandle = CreateFile(("COM2"),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
        NULL);
```

How I create my data:

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    int len;
    char data[1];
}Message;
```

(and later in my main function)

```cpp
    message.len = 8;
    message.data[0] = 0x30;
```

How I call WriteFile:

```cpp
    OVERLAPPED osWriteS = { 0 };
    osWriteS.Offset = 0;
    osWriteS.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    DWORD bytesSent;

    _cprintf("message: %x\r\n", message.data[0]);
    _cprintf("message len: %i\r\n", message.len);

    if (WriteFile(serialPortHandle, message.data, message.len, &bytesSent, &osWriteS) == false)
    {
        _cprintf("bytes sent before overlap: %x\n", bytesSent);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            _cprintf("Failed to send message\n");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            bool _overlappedResult = GetOverlappedResult(serialPortHandle, &osWriteS, &bytesSent, TRUE);
            _cprintf("overlapped: %x\n", _overlappedResult);
            _cprintf("bytes: %x\n", bytesSent);
        }
    }


    if (bytesSent != message.len)
    {
        _cprintf("Failed to send complete message\n");
        return;
    }
```

Printing `GetOverlappedResult` returns a value of `1`, yet the `bytesSent = 0` despite the message containing `1 byte`, and no data was received from another serial port waiting for this to send data.

Could anyone please help me provide insight to the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your application correctly. Do you use a serial-port if so where do you open the port with the baud rate databits stopbits and parity?

Comment: Hi @B.Letz , I've actually managed to solve the problem, but thank you for your reply! I'll try to find time to post my solution so others might reference it. 

To answer your question, yes I did use the serial-port right after creating it using `CreateFile(...)`.